# How do i connect to wifi using terminal on an ubuntu server?

Tags: server

I am extremely new to linux and this is my first installation on an old laptop to host a minecraft server for my friends. I don't remember being prompted to add a wifi network in setup, maybe i accidentally skipped it somehow but now i can't run ifconfig to find my ip and when i am prompted to use sudo apt-get install net-tools it tells me it failed to fetch "http://archive.ubuntu.com/pool/main/n/net-tools/net-tools_1.60%2bgit20181103.0eebece-1ubuntu5_amd64.deb" and then it tells me to run apt get update (which tells me the file is locked) or --fix-missing (which comes up as command not found). I asked my nerd friend about this and he said i probably wasn't connected to a wifi network which must be it as i never entered any wifi credentials. Is there any way i can either connect to the wifi through terminal or go through the setup process again since i dont have anything i need to save anyway? Thanks in advance and sorry if this is a duplicate, i tried to find any similar posts for my issue but had no luck.

Comment: Can you take the laptop to an ethernet cable and plug it in temporarily? If so, you'll be able to install and use tools like `nmcli` and `nmtui` which make it easier to get on wifi.

Comment: Or usb tether using a phone.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo nmcli dev wifi con ssid password secret
```

Comment: "sudo: nmcli: command not found"